# MatrixToImageWriter from zxing library in Java isn't recognized

Tags: java, zxing

My project is in Java, Eclipse, latest versions both, and I am working on windows 10. The problem is, I am trying to import this library:
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.MatrixToImageWriter;
but it isn't recognized, although all other zxing libraries are recognized. I downloaded the jar for zxing library from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.5.1
and I can assure you, I set it up correctly, because, again, all my other zxing libraries are recognized. I also refreshed 10000 times the project but it still doesn't work. Can you help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need another dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```